# Moving average Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm looking for a way to calculate the average turnover of the past 4 weeks.

[image: Screenshot of the sheet]

The formula I used to determine to current year/weeknumber is:

```
=year(now())&"_"&0&(WEEKNUM(now();21))
```

The current year/week is 2021_05.

So I'm looking for a way to adding up the values of:

`2021_01 + 2021_02 + 2021_03 + 2021_04`

The number I'm looking for is the sum of these values `(33.344 + 30.360 + 27.192 + 30.000)` divided by `4`.

Also the (moving) average should be excluded from zeros and empty cells.

Is there a way to calculate the average of the last 4 weeks in Google Sheets?